# How can tests be done to understand HTTP deeply in program

Tags: http, web, backend

I‘m learning HTTP protocol for developing web backend program. I'm reading some chapters of HTTP_The Definitive Guide. I find there are many concepts in that book and want to test all the concepts in program. For example, test
basic authentication, cookies and so on. How can I do these tests to understand concepts deeply in program?

Comment: Programming language + 'socket' = send and receive bytes. About as low-level as you can get without having to control voltages :p I take it you don't have much programming experience? ...maybe a packet inspection tool like Wireshark.

Comment: @ ABuckau As for 'socket', I usually program in c. But for HTTP,  passing and parse messages need to inspect packets. I think it's a little inconvenient to do tests with C.